# After installing an Ad-Aware update on my netbook it can no longer connect to my wireless internet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, connection

Windows XP on a Toshiba netbook.

I installed an update to Ad-Aware which required a restart and ever since it hasn't been able to connect to my wireless internet. I know my connection is good because it works on my other laptop and iPod Touch. It just says it's disconnected. I've tried repairing it and restarting multiple times. What can I do to fix this? Is this an issue regarding the Ad-Aware update or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my personal experience with AdAware I would not suspect an AdAware upgrade to cause this problem.  (But that's only my experience, not yours.)

- Did you create a System Restore Point before the upgrade?  Or perhaps AdAware was kind enough to do it for you?  Start | All Programs | Accessories | System Tools | System Restore
- Did you tweak anything else around the same time, no matter how innocuous it might have seemed at the time?  (Did you upgrade your wireless card drivers, for example?)

As a last resort, barring any luck with other suggestions, you could always "install" your wireless card from scratch, which should (in theory at least) recreate the configuration necessary.  But, again, that should be your last resort.

Comment: I did nothing else, installed the new Ad-Aware and after the restart I haven't been able to connect it. I didn't create a system restore point, but maybe Ad-Aware did, how do I know if it did or not?

Comment: Open up that app I mentioned above (Start | All Programs...), select "Restore my computer to an eaerlier time", click Next, in the calendar select the date that you performed the AdAware update and see if the list on the right side shows an entry like, "08:25:18 AdAware update" (or something indicating that AdAware created a restore point on your behalf.)  At this point if you click Next the items listed here will be restored to that time:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Restore#Resources_monitored